# How to center Task Manager (taskbar) on 5.1 LXQt Panel?

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt

I would like some guidance on how to center Task Manager (taskbar) on the 5.1 LXQt Panel, moving it from the left to the middle of it.

This is what a mean :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking for a way to center my taskbar on LXQt and I figured out something which I hope will help you:

Step 1: Go to your taskbar, make sure your cursor does not point to any icon and right-click.

Step 2: Select "Configure Panel"

Step 3: Make sure you alignment is set to "Center" under Alignment and Position.

Step 4: Under the size section, you should see "Length". Adjust the length percentage (keep it close to 50%) and you will be able to center your taskbar.

I am happy to contribute. It is my first time ever.

Comment: You don't actually say how the centring is achieved in the end, after seeing to 50% width it seems there is a step missing?

Comment: Thanks for your remark. Yes, I forgot to mention that alignment should have the value "center", now it is okay.